# Android setTextSize TextView moves baseline and cuts off text height

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to resize a TextView with the background image. I have a class that extends the TextView class, and is being added as such:

```
    MyCustomTextView tv2 = new MyCustomTextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new          
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    myLayout.addView(v);
```

and I am zooming like so in my custom TextView class:

```
    public float getScaledTextHeight()
    {
        float textHeightDPI = initial_size/windowHeight_inDPI;
        float textOnScreenHeight = textHeightDPI * windowHeight_inDPI;
        float scaledText = textOnScreenHeight * mZoom;
        return scaledText;
    }
    public void setZoomTextHeight(float zoom)
    {
        mZoom = zoom;
        image_size = getScaledTextHeight();

        float mX = ((offset_x + img_offset_x) * mZoom);
        float mY = ((offset_y + img_offset_y) * mZoom);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position1 =
                (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)this.getLayoutParams();

        position1.leftMargin = (int)mX;
        position1.topMargin  = (int)mY;
        position1.bottomMargin  = (int)(window_height - (position1.topMargin + 
                                   image_size + 16));
        this.setLayoutParams(position1);

        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX , image_size);

        invalidate();
    }
```

What ends up happening is that making the text bigger will correctly resize the TextView, but making the text smaller will keep the same base line as when it was big. It starts to cut my text out from the bottom up.

My question is, how can I move the base line so the bottom does not get cut off while resizing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

My (non)shifting baseline problem was solved by setting the buffer type to spannable. This can be done in two ways. Either set the buffer type in xml:

```
android:bufferType="spannable"
```

or call set text with the appropriate buffer type in code:

```
setText(getText(),BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

By setting the BufferType to spannable, the TextView will automatically reset the baseline accordingly. This will come at a very minor performance cost.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding in the constructor. Setting the vertical scrollbar worked just fine.

```
    this.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    this.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Worked great for me!  What the heck is going on here to make this work?

Comment: @Glenn the reason this works is because by calling setMovementMethod you inadvertantly set android:bufferType="spannable", which expects a shifting baseline.