# TextView strange Baseline after setTextSize on Nexus 7

Tags: android-layout, android

Just got the N7 for testing and have a strange Problem in one of my apps - the Baseline of a TextView is wrong ( moved to bottom ) after resizing - so the space is not totally used and the bottom of the chars are clipped - I am doing the following to set the size of my textview:

```
val_tv.setTextSize(3 * size / 4);
val_tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, size));
```

This is how it is looking on the N7:
[image]

Any hints on how I can work around this problem are very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only solution I found was not to specify pixels as height in the LayoutParams - when using WRAP_CONTENT there is no Problem ( has other disadvantages for me though )

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this annoying issue by setting the textview property

```
android:bufferType="spannable"
```

copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756965/218473)